# Why does my button have this default look

Tags: html, css

After adding CSS to my button, it still has a "default look". I think the image will explain more. I took out most of the code for other parts of the form to block out any unnecessary code
[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60I58.png)

```css
.registration-table {
  background: #192231;
}

.signup-button {
  background: #494e6b;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="registration-table">
  <th>Signup Form</th>
  <form method="POST">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="signup-button">
    <input type="submit" value="Signup"></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

Comment: Side note, your HTML is invalid. A form can't exist as the parent to a tr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have an `<input type="submit" value="Signup">` inside the `button`.

What you probably want is

`<button class="signup-button" type="submit">Signup</button>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's an issue in your implementation.

You can actually do the following:

- remove the input type `button` inside  and then add type `submit`
- or remove the `button` and add it's css class to the `<input type="button">`

```css
.signup-button {
    background: #494e6b;
    color:#ffffff;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
  <button class="signup-button" type="submit">Signup</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Signup" class="signup-button">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting all submit buttons to look the same, put it in the CSS;
`input[type=submit] {}`,
E.g.

```
input[type=submit] {
    background: #494e6b;
    color:#ffffff;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And in your html you could then remove the  element.

```
<table class="registration-table">
  <th>Signup Form</th>
  <form method="POST">
    <tr>
     <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Signup">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```